# chrome.storage.sync callback extremely slow, if it even works at all on one PC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On one of my PC's (Desktop running windows 10 and latest chrome) the callback function from chrome.storage.sync takes forever to be called, if it even happens at all. On the first page load after starting the PC the callbacks are fired off almost immediately. But for subsequent pageloads/refreshes the callbacks take several minutes or don't get fired off at all. It's occurring on several plugins I've created for personal use as well as several others from the chrome store. The failure seems to occur both when retrieving and saving data to chrome.storage.sync.

This PC has had all anti-virus & anti-malware disabled as I thought they may be the cause but the issue still persists. All extensions work fine on my other 2 PC's (Windows 7 desktop and Windows 10 laptop with latest chrome).

How on earth do I even debug this? Is it a known problem with work arounds (I haven't found anything to indicate this online)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: It's either a Chrome bug (check https://crbug.com) or something in your code.

Comment: _How on earth do I even debug this?_ Poking around with [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) might help a bit if it's file-access related (and on Windows). Also, see if you can extract any useful info from `chrome://sync-internals/`

Comment: reinstall chrome?